# Sorting by the value of the formula in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to sort data by the value of the formula.

The data is generated by a formula. I want to sort the data (and related rows) by the value of the formula output not the formula. I cannot do this.

I have created a new column. Using “paste special,” I have copied over the value derived from the formula. I can now sort the column based upon these values. However, the other columns (which contain names imported by formulae from another sheet) are not sorted correctly (that is, the content of the rows are no longer matched properly).

Comment: Have you tried to use the `SORT` formula? Perhaps you can share a doc with us?

Answer (score 1):

There is not normally any difference between sorting on values as such or sorting on the results of formulae. Column A shows the result of applying `weekday` to the chronologically entered values in ColumnB. D:E is a copy of A:B but sorted on Column D ascending.

[image: WA52638 example]

There may be issues however with certain formulae that use the likes of Row() or offset, in which case it would help if your Q specified or gave an example of such formulae.